# Уместна ли постановка тире в этих предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация

Оскорблять таких слабых людей, как он, — это скучно и неинтересно.
Потратить столько ресурсов на осуществление невыполнимой цели — бессмысленно и иррационально.

В обоих предложениях, мне кажется, постановка тире имеет право быть.

Comment: Попробуйте нажать alt+151. Или найти тире в Таблице символов.

Answer (score 2):

**Да, тире ставится в обоих случаях.**

Перед связкой ЭТО всегда ставится тире.

Во втором предложении также необходимо обозначить с помощью тире границу между группой подлежащего и сказуемым.